# How to remove html tags from string in view page C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

How to strip html tags from string in listing page in c#
I have tried `Regex.Replace(inputHTML, @"<[^>]+>|&nbsp;", "").Trim();` but this is not working in html view page may be this only work in controller.

This is my action :

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            string AuthRole = "1,2,3";
            ApplicationUser chkuser = common.CheckIsAuthorize(AuthRole);
            if (chkuser != null)
            {
                var data = db.Page.ToList();
                return View(data);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
```

This is my view :

```
foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tr>
    <td>@i</td>
    <td>@item.Title</td>
    <td>@item.Message</td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id })
    </td>
</tr>
i++;
}
```

My listing look like below :

[image]

Comment: could u plz show what will be the input and how its output look?

Comment: Please see attached image

Comment: I posted an answer. have a look on it :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want to show your content without any formatting then you can use this `Regex.Replace(input, "<.*?>", String.Empty)` to strip all of Html tags from your string.

1) Add below code to top of view (`.cshtml`).

```
@using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

@helper StripHTML(string input)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
    {
        input = Regex.Replace(input, "<.*?>", String.Empty);
        <span>@input</span>
    }
}
```

2) Use the above helper function like

```
<td>@StripHTML(item.Message)</td>
```

Comment: @ershoib how I can use in view I mean in html page

Comment: Thanks .. Working like charm

Comment: Does not work for all inputs. For instance, the input "5 is < than <b>10</b>" will output "5 is 10".

Answer (score -1):

Use mvc html helpers

@Html.Raw(item.Message)

Answer (score -4):

Replace

```
<td>@item.Message</td>
```

with

```
<td>@Html.Raw(item.Message)</td>
```

this may help you to display html in razor view

Comment: Not yet . waiting for ershoaib answer

Comment: Not sure why this answer thumb down, it works perfectly :), thanks

Comment: This answer causes the html tags to be passed as-is to the browser, making it render them. The OP is asking for a way to remove the html tags.